How can Change radioButton?
i use react-hook-form and react-table version8.
i have problem.
rows feeFlag data is [
"0",
"0",
"1",
"1",
"0"
]
"0" value possible change radiobutton no > yes > no > yes.
but, initial value "1" setting can't change 'no'
there is no reaction.
onchange event also does not work.
I have no idea what the problem is.
help.

<Controller
  name={`medias.${selectedIndex}.feeFlag`}
  control={control}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <RadioGroup
      row
      aria-label="media-feeFlag"
      name="feeFlag"
      value={field.value}
      onChange={(event) => {
        event.persist();
        field.onChange(event.target.value);
      }}
    >
      <FormControlLabel
        value={MediaFeeFlagProps.YES.toString()}
        control={<Radio />}
        label="YES"
        labelPlacement="end"
      />
      <FormControlLabel
        value={MediaFeeFlagProps.NO.toString()}
        control={<Radio />}
        label="NO"
        labelPlacement="end"
      />
    </RadioGroup>
  )}
/>


MediaFeeFlagProps.YES = "1" / NO = "0"
